# datatable not create correct value when using date to calculate

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation, lubridate

I have a `data` and want to create some new columns based on original `data`.

```
Time1            Time2         value    number
2015-01-01       NA            1724     1
2015-01-01       2015-01-03    2946     1
2015-01-01       2015-01-03    -2946    -1
2016-12-09       NA            -2182    -1
```

I explain what I want to do:
1. I want to create 4 new columns(`Begin`, `End`, `MonthEnd`, `value2`).
2. `Time1`, `Time2`, `Begin`, `End`, `MonthEnd` are date format(`POSIXct format`)
3. `value` and `value2` are numeric.
4. `number` is character.
5. IF `number`=1 THEN `Begin`=`Time1`; IF `number`=-1 and `Time2` not equal to NA THEN `Begin`=`Time2`; else `Begin`=`Time1`.
6. `End` is next year of `Time1`. (ex. `Time1`=2015-01-01, `End`=2016-01-01)
7. `MonthEnd` is the *last day of month* of `Time1`. (ex. `Time1`=2015-01-01, `MonthEnd`=2015-01-31. Since last day of Jan is 31)

First, I create these new columns:

```
data[,Begin:= Time2][number==1, Begin:= Time1][is.na(Begin), Begin:= Time1][]
data[,End:=Time1+months(12)]
data[,MonthEnd:=Time1]
day(data$MonthEnd) <- days_in_month(data$Time1)
```

Therefore, the result based on above code is:

```
Time1           Time2        Begin         End            MonthEnd          value    number
2015-01-01      NA           2015-01-01    2016-01-01     2015-01-31        1724     1
2015-01-01      2015-01-03   2015-01-01    2016-01-01     2015-01-31        2946     1
2015-01-01      2015-01-03   2015-01-03    2016-01-01     2015-01-31        -2946    -1
2016-12-09      NA           2016-12-09    2017-12-09     2016-12-31        -2182    -1
```

Second, I create `value2` based on above new `data`:

```
data[, value2 := value*pmax(0,MonthEnd - Begin) / as.numeric(End - Time1)]
```

I get:

```
value2
12242762
20920636
-19525926.58  
-11363138.6
```

However, this is false.
Take first obs. as an example. This is the true value.

```
Time1 = as.Date("2015-01-01")
Begin = as.Date("2015-01-01")
End   = as.Date("2016-01-01")
MonthEnd = as.Date("2015-01-31")
value2 = value * max(0,MonthEnd - Begin) / as.numeric(End - Time1)
value2
[1] 141.6986
```

Here is the `str(data)`:

```
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  105907 obs. of  7 variables:
$ Time1       : POSIXct, format: "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" ...
$ Time2       : POSIXct, format: NA "2015-01-03" "2015-01-03" NA ...
$ Begin       : POSIXct, format: "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" ...
$ End         : POSIXct, format: "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" ...
$ MonthEnd    : POSIXct, format: "2015-01-31" "2015-01-31" "2015-01-31" "2015-01-31" ...
$ value       : num  1724 2946 -2946 -2182 ...
$ number      : chr  "1" "1" "-1" "-1" ...
- attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
```

Moreover, I test whether date format(`POSIXct format`) influences the result. So I try:

```
Time1 <- as.POSIXct("2015-01-01")
Begin <- as.POSIXct("2015-01-01")
End <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-01")
MonthEnd <- as.POSIXct("2015-01-31")
value <- 1724
value2 <- value * pmax(0, MonthEnd - Begin) / as.numeric(End - Time1)
value2
[1] 141.6986
```

Thus, I think this problem is due to `data.table`.
Is `datatable` cannot create correct value with calculating date? Bug? Or my code is wrong?
Any suggestion? Appreciate.

**UPDATE**

```
sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.3 (2017-03-06)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950  LC_CTYPE=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950   
[3] LC_MONETARY=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950 LC_NUMERIC=C                                
[5] LC_TIME=Chinese (Traditional)_Taiwan.950   

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dplyr_0.5.0       lubridate_1.6.0   readxl_1.0.0      data.table_1.10.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] lazyeval_0.2.0   magrittr_1.5     R6_2.2.0         assertthat_0.1   DBI_0.5-1        tools_3.3.3      tibble_1.2      
 [8] Rcpp_0.12.9      cellranger_1.1.0 stringi_1.1.2    stringr_1.1.0
```

**Problem Solved**
The problem is `POSIXct, format`.
R considers these date columns to calculate with `seconds units`.
Thus, using `difftime()` and set `units = 'day'` will work.
Or, `as.Date()` will work as well.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem. Please, can you [edit] your question and add the output of `sessionInfo()`. Thank you.

Comment: In addition please check the result of `data[, End - Time1]` on your system. It should contain something like  _Time differences in days_.

Comment: ur right. So, `data[, as.numeric(End - Time1)]` should work.

Comment: @UweBlock i ADD `sessionInfo()`, plz check it.

Comment: No packages attached?

Comment: Please, show also which versions of `data.table` and `lubridate` you are using.

Comment: I edit it. check plz. maybe ur problem that cannot reproduce is also others. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce the problem on my PC with R version 3.4.0 Patched, `data.table` 1.10.4, and `lubridate` 1.6.0. So, I can't confirm that this is a `data.table` problem or bug as the OP has argued.

The OP is right that class `POSIXct` counts the number of seconds since the origin *1970-01-01 UTC* while class `Date` counts the number of days. However, this shouldn't cause any problems as `value2` is calculated using the quotient of the differences of `POSIXct` timestamps. So, it shouldn't matter whether the quotient is computed from differences in seconds or days (as long as numerator and denominator use the same units of measure). I've verified on my system, that the result is the same when I use class `Date`.

On my system, the difference between two `POSIXct` timestamps is returned in number of days:

```
str(data)
#Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  8 variables:
# $ Time1   : POSIXct, format: "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2016-12-09"
# $ Time2   : POSIXct, format: NA "2015-01-03" "2015-01-03" NA
# $ value   : int  1724 2946 -2946 -2182
# $ number  : int  1 1 -1 -1
# $ Begin   : POSIXct, format: "2015-01-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-01-03" "2016-12-09"
# $ End     : POSIXct, format: "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-01-01" "2017-12-09"
# $ MonthEnd: POSIXct, format: "2015-01-31" "2015-01-31" "2015-01-31" "2016-12-31"
# $ value2  : num  142 242 -226 -132
# - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 
# - attr(*, "index")= atomic  
#  ..- attr(*, "__number")= int  3 4 1 2

data[, End - Time1]
#Time differences in days
#[1] 365 365 365 365
```

(See `?difftime`).

However, I see the following options going forward:

1. Make sure you have the latest versions of R, `data.table`, and `lubridate` installed.
2. Compute time differences using `difftime()` explicitely, i.e.,

   ```
   data[, value2 := value * pmax(0, difftime(MonthEnd, Begin, units = "days")) /   
          as.numeric(difftime(End, Time1, units = "days"))]
   ```
3. Start computations with `data` where the initial time stamp columns are coerced to class `Date`, e.g.,

   ```
   data[, c("Time1", "Time2") := lapply(.SD, as.Date), .SDcols = c("Time1", "Time2")]
   ```

Comment: I still cannot know why it calculates with `seconds`. I think it is because of my raw data? not sure. Ur `coerced` in the last line is great.

Comment: Another small question: is that `units = "days"` or `units = day`? or they are the same?

Comment: If you are only dealing with full days, it might be better to use the `Date` class instead of `POSIXct`. I believe its "days" but I would have to look it up in the help `?difftime`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the problem several times but it works as you wish. I used R 3.4 with data.table 1.10.4 and lubridate 1.6.0. Probably upgrade can help.

Comment: I  know the problem. R consider my date `MonthEnd - Begin`with seconds`, so it calculates not based on `days`. I don't know why